# VBA Chamando programa em Python

Tags: python-3.x, vba, excel-vba

Olá, Trabalho a algum tempo desenvolvendo em VBA. porém estou começando a aprender Python e Surgiu a seguinte Dúvida ... é possível unir essas suas linguagens ? pois não encontrei nada no google que me ajudou. A minha ideia é desenvolver ações em python e fazer botoes no vba chamar essa programação ! vi até uma matéria que a microsoft estava estudando migrar a linguagem do excel de VBA para Python, ou ter compatibilidade com as Duas, mas acredito que ainda não ocorreu essa mudança !

Comment: O mais próximo que já vi foi o [PyXLL](https://www.pyxll.com/)... Você pode programar funções em python e usar no Excel. E, segundo [esse link](https://www.pyxll.com/faq/python-as-vba-replacement.html), substituir o VBA por Excel.

Comment: Acredito de para usar o [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/) com VBA

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo estes dois métodos

> Utilizar o método Shell da bibliotaca **RetVal**:

```
dim Retval
executarScript = Shell("<localização do executável python.exe> " & "<localização do script>")
```

> Criar um web service pelo python, rodando na sua máquina ou remotamente:

```
Dim httpObject As Object
 Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

 req = "https://localhost:XXXX/webservice/fazer-receber_algo"

 httpObject.Open "GET", req, False
 httpObject.send
 resultado = httpObject.responseText
```

Tem bibliotecas para comunicação dos dois, mas não vale a pena utilizar pelos bugs, documentação desnecessariamente complexa, além de serem projetos abandonados.